# Service and notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have created an android application which has a service that communicates with a database and retrieves a value every 1 hour (through a thread) for sending it to the main application and do something with it. I have set my application to run on phone boot, so that the service can run in background continuously and do the database communication I described above.
My question is if I want to push a notification message when a value changes to my database and then open the main application by clicking to notification message, this must be done by the service or by the main application? 
I suppose that the code must be write to the service and into the thread that does the database communication but I don' t know where and how. Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your Service just build and trigger the display of the notification (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) on how to do that) and it will show up. You don't need an Activity context for that, the Service context is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code for triggering Notification in your Service class itself and can specify what to do when clicking on Notification